# Uniformly convergence on a set implies a smaller set

Tags: infinite-product

Here is a product, that looks like this $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n(z)$. There are two questions:

- If you have shown that the product is uniformly convergent on a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, is this product then defined on $\mathbb{C}$? Or does it require to show that it is uniformly on **every** compact subsets?
- If you have shown that the infinite product is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ does it imply that it is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus B$, where $B$ is any set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first question, you'll have to show it's convergent on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The identity theorem does not extend to uniform convergence...

Since every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\backslash B$ can be obtained by removing $B$ from a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ the answer to the second question is yes.

Comment: Why is it necessary on the first question?

Comment: @Hopeless Infinite products are more or less the same as infinite series, because of the functional equation of $\log$: $\log( \Pi_i a_i) = \sum_i \log(a_i)$. For the latter it is standard that you need uniform convergence on every compact subset of a given open set to conclude existence of the limit on the whole open set. If you need a counterexample you can work your way back from a power series which converges only on, say, the unit disc to a corresponding product.

Comment: OK, looks like you have answered my questions. I'll accept it. I have one last question, sorry. If you have shown that $\prod_{n=N}^{\infty}p_n(z)$ is uniformly convergent for all $|z|\leq R$ for large $N$, does it imply that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n(z)$ is uniformly convergent on every compact subset as well?

Comment: @Hopeless (Uniform) convergence always relates to the behaviour of a sequence or series for $n\ge N$ for some, possibly large, $N$, so in general the answer to your question is 'yes', if this is true for every $R>0$. The choice of $N$ should, however, not depend on the choice of $R$, if it does you should careful analyze the dependency. This assumes, of course, that all $p_n$ are well defined and continuous everywhere.